# Showing $n$ is composite.

Tags: number-theory

So I'm trying to show that n=3953 is composite. 
The information I have is that a does not equal $1(\mod p)$ and that if $a^2 = 1 (\mod p)$ then $a = -1 (\mod p)$. I also know $p$ is a prime and that $a=2949$. Now I'm very confused as to how to use this information to show that n is composite seeing as there's been no previous mention of n. If someone could explain this to me, step by step I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: p is an odd prime

Comment: There's not been a mention of n in the question which is why I'm confused and was wondering if maybe I'm lacking in some knowledge

Comment: $\sqrt {3953}\sim 63$ so the search for prime factors is pretty simple.

Comment: The easiest way to show that $n=3953$ is composite, is noting that $59\cdot 67=3953$

Comment: I'm supposed to use the information about a/p to prove this

Comment: But then there must be some connection between $n,a$ and $p$.

Comment: I mean...you could solve the congruence $a^2\equiv 1 \pmod {3953}$ to get $a\in \{1,1004, 2949,3952\}$ which immediately shows that $3953$ is composite but of course that is $\textit{ a lot}$ harder than just searching for a prime factor.

Comment: Just to say, $1249^2-1=1560000 = 2^6\times 3\times 5^4\times 13 $ which has no apparent connection to $3953$.

Comment: You might be misinterpreting something - could yo give a more verbatim copy of the problem statement?

Comment: I just realised that I've written the incorrect number, it should be 2949. I'll edit now.

Comment: In this case we have $2949^2\equiv 1\mod 3953$ , but $2949\neq \pm1\mod 3953$ which is enough to show that $n$ is composite. $\gcd(a-1,n)$ and $\gcd(a+1,n)$ will both give a non-trivial factor., in this case  actually the prime factors of $n$.

Comment: But still it is confusing that $a^2\equiv 1\mod p$ is given instead of $a^2\equiv 1\mod n$

Comment: Yeah, the fact that it was mod p and not mod n was what was really throwing me off and it left me really confused.

Comment: Their point is that for primes, $p$, we can demonstrate that the only solutions to the congruence $a^2\equiv 1 \pmod p$ are $\pm 1 \pmod p$.  Thus if you have found a non-trivial solution to that congruence for some modulus $n$ then you have shown that $n$ is not a prime.  To be sure, this is not very helpful as a primality test.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

For a prime $p$ we have the nice fact that the congruence $$a^2\equiv 1\pmod p$$ has exactly two solutions (namely $a\equiv \pm 1 \pmod p$).  It follows that if, for some $n$, you have a solution to $a^2\equiv 1 \pmod n$ which is neither $1$ nor $-1\pmod n$, $n$ can not be a prime.  In this case it is easy to verify (by direct computation) that $$2949^2\equiv 1 \pmod {3953}$$ and, as $2949$ is plainly neither $1$ nor $-1\pmod {3953}$, we can be assured that $3953$ is not a prime.

To be sure, this is not a terribly efficient test for primality.  In this case, of course, it depended on someone directing our attention to $2949$.  Of course one could have found it, or $1004$ which works just as well, by a search, but all of that is considerably harder than just searching for prime factors of $3953$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$\sqrt{3953}\approx 63$$
you only have to check all prime numbers below and equal to 63 if they divide $n$ equally.

Since
$$3953 \bmod 59 \equiv 0$$
$n$ isn't a prime.